# Changing value of searchResponse.total when using ScrollSearch in ElasticSearch NEST API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am performing scroll-search on Elasticsearch 5.3.0 via C# NEST API. The searchResponse.Total initially has 12522 hits. I fetch 100 documents in each scroll request. This way the number of fetched documents increments until 11300 apprx. However after this suddenly searchResponse.Total value starts to decrease as 7437 then 4000 until it reaches 0 or value lower than number of documents already read.

The code I am using is as follows :

```
List<ClusterJob> clusterJobData = new List<ClusterJob>();
var counter = 0;

var searchResponse = client.Search<ClusterJob>(search => search
            .Index("privateIndex")
            .Type("privateType")
            .Size(100)
            .Sort(ss => ss.Ascending(ff => ff.Request.RequestedTimeStamp))
            .Scroll("5m")

while (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
        {
            if (searchResponse.Documents.Count > 0)
            {
                clusterJobData.AddRange(searchResponse.Documents);
            }
            counter += searchResponse.Documents.Count;
            var results = searchResponse;
            var retryCount = 0;
            do
            {
                searchResponse = client.Scroll<ClusterJob>("1m", results.ScrollId);
                Task.Delay(100);
                retryCount++;
                //Retry 3 times if request fails
            } while (retryCount < 0 && !searchResponse.IsValid);
            if (!searchResponse.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to fetch Data");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Lines Read : " + counter + "/" + searchResponse.Total);
        }
```

My network speed is sufficiently good and I am keeping the search context open deliberately for long time. Any hints as to this unusual behavior of reducing searchResponse.total when code runs? Is this possibly a bug? I came across an old bug linked but unsure if this issue still persists : [ElasticSearch Issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/totalhits-gets-changed-unexpectedly-while-scrolling-searchresponse/3366/3)

Some information on my ES configuration if it helps :

- Distributed across 5 VM cluster of 5 nodes
- 14 gb heap space allocation to each instance
- Version : 5.3.0
- 64-bit Running as a service on each VM

Comment: Have you seen the need to retry scroll requests when `!searchResponse.IsValid`? Do you have a log of requests (including retries) that you can share?

Comment: I was logging same to console however only time when `!searchResponse.IsValid` is when request times out. That is the point where total hits is changed on retry attempt. I will try shifting the log to text file instead if it will help.

Comment: I suspect a number a few different scenarios might be happening here. Does the `scroll_id` change on each iteration?

Comment: No `scroll_id` remains same on each request. Ok after some check here is more info: I can retreive documents fast without any loss if I apply source filtering to only return specific fields which I need currently. The documents in my current index are considerably large and nested.